# In Django, can I create an extra custom manager for a reverse ManyToMany relationship?

Tags: django, django-models

I want to create an extra manager for fetching a filtered version of a reverse ManyToMany relationship. I have these models:

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    # ...
    is_public = models.BooleanField()

    albums = models.ManyToManyField('Album')

class Album(models.Model):
    # ...
```

I can get all the photos in an album with `album.photo_set.all()`. I'd like to provide a way to get only the *public* photos in an album by doing `album.photo_set.public()` (which would, somewhere, do a `.filter(is_public=True)`).

I guess I'm wanting to provide an extra [Related manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/relations/), but I'm not sure that's possible. I don't want, or need, to replace the default related manager (which sounds like a bad idea anyway). I don't need a custom through model for the relationship, unless that's the only way to achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, you could make a related manager but that seems a bit overkill for this.

Why not just simply add a function to your model that returns only the public photos in the album?

```
def get_public(self):

     return self.photo_set.filter(is_public = True)
```

Comment: I think I was overthinking this :) Of course, that seems nicely simple. Unless someone else comes up with some other brilliant idea I'll mark this correct later, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can create manager like this:

```
class PublicManager(models.Manager):
    use_for_related_fields = True

    def public(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs.update({
            'is_public': True
        })
        return self.get_queryset().filter(*args, **kwargs)
```